# What does 什么每天 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word

The excerpt is from [the top answer on 知乎](https://www.zhihu.com/question/26290171?sort=created):

> 再加上「真假TV」里爆出来的，**什么**每天用老公的牙刷刷马桶，把排泄物混到料理里微笑着看他吃下去之类的，可以拿去回答「人性到底可以有多阴暗」了。

According to [MDBG dictionary](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=1&wdqt=%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88):

> 什么 what? / who? / something / anything

I guess the 什么 here means "what the hell" or something like that. So the meaning of the entire sentence is something like the following:

> How can she use her husband's toothbrush to brush a toilet every day

But is my understanding correct here? What is the meaning of 什么 here and can it be used as such? Maybe more explanations about the usage in general would be helpful.

Comment: bkrs： 什么（表示惊讶或不满）:
什么，你真是这个意思? What, do you really mean it?
什么！没有钱? What! No money?
（表示责难）:
你说呀！装什么哑巴? Speak! Stop playing dumb.
（表示不同意对方刚说的话）:
什么不懂！装糊涂就是了。 What do you mean--not understand? You're just pretending.

Comment: The 什么 here is equivalent to "such as".

Comment: writers often omit commas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the usage of "什么...之类的" or "什么...啊，什么...啊", [什么](http://www.ichacha.net/hy/%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88.html) is used for citing examples, with the connotation that there're so many such kind of things.

> ⑦用在几个并列成分前面，表示列举不尽：～送个信儿啊，跑个腿儿啊，他都干得了。

(used before several parataxises, expressing can't list all of them)

For this sentence it could be translated as

> such as 每天用老公的牙刷刷马桶，and 把排泄物混到料理里微笑着看他吃下去 etc，可以拿去回答「人性到底可以有多阴暗」了。

Answer (score 1):

> 什么每天用老公的牙刷刷马桶

It's a colloquial usage. It's not a serious/formal writing I think.

什么 here could be interpreted as 像什么, 像，比如像什么， or "**something/things like**" in English.

The sentence could be rephrased as

> **像什么**每天用老公的牙刷刷马桶, ... ...
>
> **像**每天用老公的牙刷刷马桶, ... ...
>
> **Things like**, she uses her husband's toothbrush to brush a toilet every
>   day, ... ...